# Ajax, Jquery Get or Post Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Hello guys I'm working in a web app using python django as backend, and all is working fine, nowadays I have worked only with forms and sometimes with get or post option, yesterday I was trying to get info though ajax without forms, but I realized I only can use it with "get" option instead of post, Am I right?

Comment: It supports both post and get whatever you read must be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Even without forms, you can use any of the HTTP methods like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE with Django.

To make AJAX Calls which support all the HTTP methods, you can use the Django Rest Framework package (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master) with Django.